# how to add more cars into simulation, limit speed and edit traffic lights

Tags: sumo

I want to add more vehicles and change the speed.

I used the command `--max-num-vehicles 30` to try and start the simulation with more cars but for some reason the run time simulation never passes 50 or 60 active cars.

Also my simulation has traffic lights but they seem no to work properly because it only has 2 stages (Green light and Yellow light).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAQGK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `--max-num-vehicles` is to limit the number of cars not to increase it. The easiest way to get more cars is usually to define more traffic input either by using randomTrips.py with a higher period parameter (e.g. `-p 1000`) or by introducing flows with high counts into your route file, see also http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_get_high_flows.2Fvehicle_densities.3F.

Concerning the traffic light, you probably created a traffic light on a junction with just two streets. It is a known issue that sumo's netconvert does not add red phases here, because there are no conflicting flows demanding green time for them. If you are using the nightly svn version, you can use the `--tls.red.time` option to force a red time, if not you can edit them manually in netedit.

Comment: ok now I understand the use of --max-num-vehicules but that -p 1000 parameter where can I edit that, in my small project I only have these files:   trips.trips.xml, typemap.xml, map.net.xml, map.osm, map.poly.xml, map.rou.alt.xml, map.rou.xml and map.sumo.cfg

Answer (score 0):

You may have to regenerate your map.rou.xml file in order to have more vehicles. As the response above said, use the `-p 1000` to your randomTrips.py command, as an option